# Array in while loops in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently trying to use an array in a while loop in C for class.
The goal is to take the portfolio value and add it to the dividend rate, then times it by 1.10 to simulate a 10% return. When I run the program it does the first loop correctly, but all years after that show the same amount. So if I have an initial value of 1000 and a dividend rate of 5, I would expect 1105 on the first year, 1220 on the second and so on. I'm getting 1105 for every year.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: chopped out a lot of unneeded code that I don't think is pertinent to the issue.

So what I think I need to do is figure out how to increment `x`, and add the previous value to it. So if the first year was 1,000, then the second year would be it's value + 1,000. etc...

I'm trying to figure out the best way to execute that.

```
  while (year <= 19)
  {
     (totalvalue[x] = dividend + portfoliovalue *1.10); 
     year++;
     printf("The total value of the portfolio after %u year will be approximately %u.\n", year, totalvalue[x]);      
  }
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whatis this `(totalvalue[x] = dividend + portfoliovalue *1.10)`? Why the parentheses?

Comment: Please format and indent the code properly...

Comment: It doesn't seem like x is incrementing anywhere, but year is. Should you be using year as the index for totalValue?

Comment: I can't figure out why do you expect the value to change if neither `dividend` nor `portfoliovalue` change inside the loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  There should be no need for all that I/O in `main()` - or for our systems to have an external program called `PAUSE`.

Comment: need to feed back the `totalvalue` into the `portfoliovalue` so the value of the portfolio increases in value, before performing the next loop

Answer (score 4):

The formula `totalvalue[x] = dividend + portfoliovalue *1.10` doesn't make any use of `year` or any previous value etc and so is clearly wrong as it doesn't use any value that actually changes in the loop. I'm not going to put in the "full answer" as you have said this is homework.

In addition you don't need an array just to print the values. If you do want an array to keep the values for something else later then you probably want to index on `year` and not `x`.

Comment: Yes I think I have it mostly figured out. This may not be the best way but adding 'totalvalue[x-1]' to the formula allows the loop to display the amounts, but they are the wrong amounts. It's taking the initial amount and treating it as a recurrent amount.
Could this be fixed by moving the operation out of the loop, then creating a new operation to take the initial amount from the first function?

Comment: Your big problem is that the formula has "no moving parts". No value used in the formula gets changed in the loop so it will always do the same thing every time. There are 2 sides to this: `x` doesn't change so `totalvalue[x]` is always the same "target". Nothing on the RHS changes so it is always the same "value". Surely you want some sort of relationship between the values for say year 6 and year 7 on to year 8 etc...